# how to save xml parse output results in csv format

Tags: batch-file

below batch script reads xml file and extracts required tag/values and saves them in output file but problem is, all the required tag values gets saved one below the other in column A. I wanted each of the tag values to get stored under in each of there respective tag headers. Any help is much appreciated.

xml input file content :

```
<RIMP>
<HSI>
<SN>Pro Gen8</SN>
<SP>Podt1</SP>
<UUID>ILD9V</UUID>
<VIRTUAL>
<PN>Inte 4</PN>
<VID>
<BSN></BSN>
<TYPE>Admin</TYPE>
</VID>
</VIRTUAL>
<PRODUCTID> 9A          </PRODUCTID>
<NICS>
<NIC>
<PORT>1</PORT>
<MACADDR></MACADDR>
</NIC>
</RIMP>
```

code :

```
 set inFile="C:\output\input.xml"
    set outFile="C:\output.csv"
    set req_tags=SN UUID PN TYPE
    for %%a in (%inFile%) do (
        for %%c in (%req_tags%) do (
            set "found="
            set search_tag=%%c
            for /f "tokens=2 delims=><  " %%b in ( ' type "%%a" ^|findstr /i !search_tag! ' ) do set found=%%b
            if defined found >> "%outFile%" echo !found! 
        )
    )
```

currently getting output as : (after opening the file in text editor)

```
SPN,UUID,PN,TYPE 
Pro Gen8            
ILD9V           
Inte 4          
Admin
```

but I was trying to get output as :

```
SN,UUID,PN,TYPE 
Pro Gen8,ILD9V,Inte 4,Admin
```

After using DavidPostill code, am getting expected output now as  :

```
SN,UUID,PN,TYPE 
Pro Gen8,ILD9V,Inte 4,Admin
```

how can we add server ip/info as first column in csv file (server info is taken from serverlist file)

```
Server,SN,UUID,PN,TYPE 
11.12.13.14,Pro Gen8,ILD9V,Inte 4,Admin
```

David's code does the trick, anyone required the answer about csv format output then I would suggest please do see David's reply below.

Comment: CSV means Comma-Separated Values, but I cannot see any commas `,` in your output data... And you need to show us the XML input data too... In general I recommend another language which natively supports XML parsing, because treating it as normal text like batch files do is very cumbersome and error-prone...

Comment: I have copied the output file content from excel so, couldn't see comma. I have updated the initial post to include teh xml input file content.

Comment: So copy the CSV data with a text editor!

Comment: aschipfl, all am trying is to get the output so, when user can filter the result using spreadsheet filter option. sorry maybe csv is causing confusion here.

Comment: I'm quite shure you do not want the output exactly as it is displayed here (check out the 1st and 2nd columns); so pretty PLEASE (with sugar on top) copy the data with a text editor so it can clearly be seen...

Comment: ok, I opened the output file in text editor and here the output now .

Comment: How do you write the header line? your code does not output such! And I also meant to update the desired output...

Comment: I have used echo command as the very first line. echo SN,UUID,PN,TYPE > %outFile%. I missed to put this line in my inital post. Sorry again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I want each of the tag values to get stored under in each of there respective tag headers

Assuming you actual want a CSV file as output, using the following batch file.

**test.cmd**:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set inFile="C:\output\input.xml"
set outFile="C:\output.csv"
set req_tags=SN UUID PN TYPE
set outLine=
echo SN,UUID,PN,TYPE > %outFile% 
for %%a in (%inFile%) do (
  for %%c in (%req_tags%) do (
    set search_tag=%%c
    for /f "tokens=2 delims=><  " %%b in ('type "%%a" ^|findstr /i !search_tag!' ) do (
      if [%%b] NEQ [] (
        rem we don't want to match /BSN
        if [%%b] NEQ [/BSN] (
          set outline=!outline!%%b,
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
rem output the values
rem remove trailing ,
set outline=%outline:~0,-1%
echo %outline%>>"%outFile%"
endlocal
```

**Usage:**

```
F:\test>test

F:\test>type C:\output.csv
SN,UUID,PN,TYPE
Pro Gen8,ILD9V,Inte 4,Admin

F:\test>
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [enabledelayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) - Delayed Expansion will cause variables to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time.
- [for](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) - Conditionally perform a command several times.
- [for](http://ss64.com/nt/for2.html) - Conditionally perform a command on several files.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) - Loop command: against a set of files - conditionally perform a command against each item.
- [variables](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) - Extract part of a variable (substring).

Comment: Thanks David. you are correctly understood of what I was trying to achieve. with your code, everything works as expected but found out that first req_tags value gets displayed twice not sure why thou. I have update original post to show what output getting now

Comment: @Prime I can't reproduce that using the test file in your question.

Comment: Sorry David. my mistake, I re-ran the your code and this time it worked without any first tag value repeating in the output csv file. Thanks again. Is it possible to add server ip/info as first header in csv file, since I need to run this script for several servers so, without having server ip/info in csv file, it will be very tough to say which row values corresponds to which server. I read the server info from serverlist file.

Comment: Of course it will be possible. You can, for example, add an extra enclosing for loop that `echo`s the server information. If you get stuck please ask a new question, referencing this one for context if necessary.

Comment: ok, will try as you suggested using extra for loop. I was thinking of creating new post, Can you please let me know how can refer this post in new post. is there any option available or just mention this post link while creating the new post. Many Many Thanks for your answer/suggestion.

Comment: Just add a link (and say why you are adding it).

Comment: I did open new post as the for loop I tried to get server info was not working. I still get full serverFile path  Can you please have a look and let me know where am making mistake. [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38722347/getting-server-details-in-output-csv-file-using-batch-script